# How do I deal with a bad close?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Mods do not always exercise perfect judgement, how is a user supposed to deal with a bad close?

Comment: Turns out to be the same topic, but assumes that reopening is the answer to bad modding, which is what I was unaware of, and asking about, directly.

Comment: If a question is closed when it shouldn't be, you reopen it.  Whether it is closed by a mod or not is irrelevant.  If a moderator shows a history of consistent improper actions, that is an entirely separate matter  from one action that you disagree on.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is worthy of being down voted. This is a perfectly legitimate question I would also like to have answered.

Comment: @Mitch The question demonstrates no research effort.  Taking the time to do something as simple as looking through the FAQ table of contents clearly answers this question.  Not taking the time to do such trivial research is an entirely justifiable reason for downvoting a question.  See the downvote tooltip, "This question does not show any research effort;" which is clearly the case here.

Comment: Why does it not surprise me that the same trigger happy mod that closes the original question I'm interested in VTCs the question about the original closure. Bad mod, no cookie.

Comment: I searched for several minutes before posting, if I didn't find the answer it's because I didn't know it was the answer. There are no dupes of "how do I deal with a bad close"~

Comment: If it's so trivial then why don't you help answer the question?

Comment: @Mitch I proposed a duplicate, which has an answer to the question.  Why did you not even take the time to do something as simple as looking at the proposed duplicate if you want to find an answer to the question?  Why would I take the time to repeat the same answer, over and over again, when I could instead just link to the relevant FAQ question?

Comment: @Servy Not all of us have honed the ability to search exactly for the answers we are looking for on here. Sometimes we need answers to questions were not sure how to ask. Should we be ignored, down-voted and reprimanded because we asked a question that someone else has already answered 10 years ago?

Comment: @Mitch First off, nobody was ignored.  The person was given an answer to his question within just a few minutes of asking it.  Next, it's certainly worthwhile to take the time to look through the frequently asked questions when you have a question that you would like to ask, especially if it's about something that seems like it might come up often.  Were this not an FAQed question, then sure, it likely wouldn't have been easy to find, but because it is, it *is* easy to find; to the point that I feel that the author ought to have found it before asking, which I can express through a downvote.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I thought the way this forum worked was through asking questions and up-voting the best answers. How exactly doesn't down voting encourage or help anyone? Also, the one person who did answer got 5 down-votes. Not sure on how doing things "Your way" is helpful at-all.

Comment: @Mitch 1. SE is not a forum, 2. All voting is anonymous, 3. Downvoting on meta often means disagreement (as is mine, not that I am in any way obliged to explain why)

Answer (score -5):

Maybe the answer is supposed to be cast a reopen vote? Maybe I'm oblivious but I did not even know this feature existed, and I bet that a lot of other users don't either, it appears to be intentionally understated.

Comment: I just linked to an FAQ question discussing how to reopen a question, it's right on the privileges list, there's a "reopen" link on any question you have the ability to reopen.  All and all, it's a reasonably discoverable feature.  In what way do you feel it should be advertised that it currently is not?

Comment: In the description of the closure it should advise the user that casting a reopen vote is the way to object to the closure, maybe. I disagree, it's not a very discoverable feature, probably because it's used so rarely. Thanks for a link. Though it was not the direct answer to the simple question that I posed.

Comment: It's an *exact* answer to the question that you posted.  You asked how to deal with a question that is closed when it shouldn't be, the proposed duplicate is the *exact* same question.  The wording is slightly different, but the question is the same.

Comment: No, it's an exact answer to "how do I reopen", you're assuming that I knew that reopen was the mechanism for disagreeing with close, which seems obvious, but slipped past me.

Comment: The fact that you didn't know the correct term, and thus used a synonymous term, in no way makes the question not a duplicate, nor does it somehow prevent the answers from applying to your completely synonymous question.

Comment: Yes, I believe it does. In fact, it's the exact reason I wasn't able to find the question on reopening.

Comment: So after having read the question you are still completely clueless as to what to do when you come across a question that is closed, that you don't feel should be closed?  If so, I find that...astonishing.

Comment: Do not be so narrow minded as to assume that there is only one question that corresponds to an answer.

Comment: But it's not a different question.  It's exactly the same question, merely expressed using synonyms.  That's the *exact* reason that the proposed duplicate feature exists.  And in any case, it wouldn't matter even if it's not.  You still get the answer to your question either way.  Why is it important to you that someone take the time to write up the exact same answer again just for you?

Comment: Didn't I explain that I did not know that casting reopen votes was the answer? I don't think I can be any clearer about this.